# strtotime() Is Adding An Extra Day

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime

Can anybody tell me why `strtotime()` seems to be adding 1 day? This seems to only happen in the late afternoon (something like 7 or 8 PM), otherwise it says the correct day.

```
echo date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
```

Output:

> 12/21/2015 08:34:43 pm

```
echo gmdate('l, F jS, Y', strtotime(date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time())));
```

Output:

> Tuesday, December 22nd, 2015

I would like the above output, however, I want today's date (the 21st not the 22nd).

Comment: I smell that Timezones are at fault here. You are feeding it local time, and when it converts, it converts to UTC probably, then you convert it back to local time, which is 6 hours ahead because you're somewhere in Texas or something. I'm too lazy to answer, but if you can google how to manage time zone with all of these functions, you'll be a happy camper without me lifting even a finger :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `date` instead of `gmdate`.

You are using `gmdate()` which gets the date in UTC. The problem only happens late in the afternoon/evening because at those times it *really is* the next day in UTC time.

You're also doing too much work - you can simplify that line of code to this:

```
// echo gmdate('l, F jS, Y', strtotime(date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time())));
echo date('l, F jS, Y');
```

Otherwise you've created a timestamp from a time string based on the current time stamp. You could just leave the second parameter to date empty and the current time "now" is assumed.

It is also very important to make sure you are calling `date_default_timezone_set` somewhere or that you have it configured in your `php.ini`.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to post this solution after figuring out what timezone issues he had. Right on time :)

Answer (score 0):

This detail in your code...

```
echo gmdate('l, F jS, Y', strtotime(date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time())));
```

(= the "gmdate") will *always* return Greenwich Mean Time (GMT), which is London/UK.

So change that to `date(....`

And add `date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');` anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Decided to ultimately use:

```
$date = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'), new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$timestamp = $date->format('U');
$date = gmdate('l, F jS, Y', $timestamp);
```

based on Alexander's comment.